# How can I view all the inherited (Overideable) methods of a super class in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I say

```
class Foo extends Bar{

}
```

What's the easiest (read most IDE specific) way to examine the inherited (and Overideable) members of Bar in Eclipse? I can't seem to find any panel or window where I can see those and their accompanying docs (if any are attached).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Control O shows all of the current methods in this class. Control O again show all methods plus all the methods from its ancestors. An F next to the method name denotes it as being final.

You can then use the arrow keys to select a specific method and then enter to go to its declaration and associated javadoc.

**EDIT**

You can also just do control space somewhere in the body of a class(outside of a method or inner class) and code complete will show you which methods you can overide

[image]